# gvim on windows - compiled ycm plugin now crashing on start

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, plugin-you-complete-me, crash

I installed the **YouCompleteMe**(*YCM*) plugin and compiled it using the provided instructions, one after the other for all options excluding rust. Below is a reproduction of the commands I ran, the reason for running one after the other is that I got an error running them all together and it was easier to read when doing one by one.

```
cd %USERPROFILE%/vimfiles/bundle/YouCompleteMe
python install.py --clang-completer  
python install.py --omnisharp-completer
python install.py --gocode-completer
python install.py --tern-completer
```

These ran, then I restarted my system due to another issue(was installing driver updates) when I then started GVim it crashed. I can open vim in the shell but it doesn't recognize Vundle and none of the plugins it manages are working there. I don't know if that was the case before, I haven't been using the shell for editing on Windows 10.

*Please advise!*

---

## Response to comments

*fruglemonkey* - It was not configured for use on Windows, it was sourcing the .vimrc while I had opted to use the _vimrc purely for separation of concerns(keep the .vimrc for *nix environments and _ for windows) I copied the _vimrc to .vimrc and Vundle now works, though it doesn't recognise the colour scheme in use. I presume it isn't sourcing from the vim directory that GVim is using is all. Even now that it's sourcing properly it isn't recognizing Gundo or anything. I don't think it's related to the crashing of GVim, but I can provide more information regarding this on request.

Comment: ```"It doesn't recognize Vundle"``` can you explain further? Error messages, logs, etc?

Comment: Have you looked at this [issue](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1894) ?